# Handle a class execution in async mode

Tags: c#

On my NET 4.5 application I have a service layer.

I use a dispatcher to send queries and receive replies:

Example: GetPostByIdQuery is handled by GetPostByIdHandler and returns GetPostByIdReply.

How can I change my code so the query is handled in async way?

```
public class Dispatcher : IDispatcher {

  public TReply Send<TReply>(Query query) where TReply : Reply, new() {

    Type type = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TReply));

    IQueryHandler handler = (IQueryHandler)ObjectFactory.GetInstance(type);

    try {

      return (TReply)handler.Handle(query);

    } catch (Exception exception) {

      ILogger logger = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ILogger>();
      logger.Send(exception);
      if (Debugger.IsAttached) throw;
      return new TReply { Exception = exception };

    }
  } // Send
}
```

UPDATE: Considering the suggestion I added:

```
public interface IDispatcher {

  TReply Send<TReply>(Query query) where TReply : Reply, new();
  Task<TReply> SendAsync<TReply>(Query query) where TReply : Reply, new();

} // IDispatcher

public class Dispatcher : IDispatcher {

  public TReply Send<TReply>(Query query) where TReply : Reply, new() {
  } // Send

  public Task<TReply> Send<TReply>(Query query) where TReply : Reply, new() {
  } // Send

}
```

TWO QUESTIONS:

1. Do I need to repeat my code inside both Send methods? Or one can call the other?
2. Instead of having two Send methods could I have one method with a boolean "sendAsync"?
   I am not sure if this make sense since the return type would be the same ...

Comment: Change your interface to return `Task<TReply>`

Comment: What specific problem do you have? Why is your case different than any other async method?

Comment: So I only need to add Task<TReply> to my interface and to my class method? I asked this because my idea was to have something like:  TReply Send<TReply>(Query query, Boolean async = false) ... So this way I would decide when to use asyn or not. Can't this be done?

Comment: @MDMoura No you can't just do that, async means your function returns immedatly and continues on to the next line after the call. What do you do with `TReply` if `Boolean async = true`? You don't have the result yet but you need to continue on to the next line of code.

Comment: Also as another tip, instead of doing `if (Debugger.IsAttached) throw;` just [enable breaking on thrown exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d14azbfh.aspx) instead of just uncaught ones. This will stop the code at the point the exception was thrown instead of inside the `catch` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "Embrace async" and get any real benefit from it you will need to modify `IQueryHandler` and make that async, as that is where the real work is being done.

You never showed us what IQueryHandler does but you would likely need to write new methods to truly support async code

```
public class Dispatcher : IDispatcher {

  public TReply Send<TReply>(Query query) where TReply : Reply, new() {
       //(Snip) No changes to the original code
  } // Send

  public async Task<TReply> SendAsync<TReply>(Query query) where TReply : Reply, new() {

    Type type = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TReply));

    IQueryHandler handler = (IQueryHandler)ObjectFactory.GetInstance(type);

    try {

      return await (TReply)handler.HandleAsync(query); //Uses the new method "Task<TResult> IQueryHandler<TQueryType, TResult>.HandleAsync(TQueryType query)"

    } catch (Exception exception) {

      ILogger logger = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ILogger>();
      logger.Send(exception);
      if (Debugger.IsAttached) throw;
      return new TReply { Exception = exception };

    }
  } // Send
}
```

If you don't care about the performance improvements of writing real async code (it may not be worth the cost of updating all of your `IQueryHandler`s) but you still want the befit of using async/await for a slow process you can make a easy wrapper by doing

```
public class Dispatcher : IDispatcher {

  public TReply Send<TReply>(Query query) where TReply : Reply, new() {
      //(Snip) No changes to the original code
  } // Send

  public Task<TReply> SendAsync<TReply>(Query query) where TReply : Reply, new() {
       return Task.Run(() => Send<TReply>(query));
  } // SendAsync
}
```

However, like I said, don't expect much performance gains from this, just convenience so your callers don't have to do it themselves (and perhaps some time in the future you could replace this with real async code without having to update any callers that uses this function).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new `SendAsync` method as such:

```
public Task<TReply> SendAsync<TReply>(Query query) where TReply : Reply, new()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return Send<TReply>(query);
    });
}
```

To answer your second question, if you wanted to only expose a method signature like `Send(Query query, bool sendAsync)`, and make your original `Send` method private, you could write something like this:

```
public dynamic Send<TReply>(Query query, bool sendAsync) where TReply : Reply, new()
{
    if (sendAsync)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return Send<TReply>(query);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return Send<TReply>(query);
    }
}
```

Similarly, an `Object` could be returned and unboxed by the caller. But writing it this way is pretty ugly; I'm just pointing out that it's possible.

Comment: This is asynchronous only in the sense that it happens in the background -- the perf reasons people like async for are not here. Wrapping a synchronous method in Task.Run() at the API level is a bad idea, because it hides an inefficiency from the user, who might have otherwise been able to better work around a synchronous call.

Comment: Instead of `dynamic` I would have just done [Task.FromResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922.aspx) and have it return `Task<TReply>` for both the sync and the async version.